# How to redirect from one page to another in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Now i am in log in page and after entering the credentials my login page should redirect to another page, In this page i want to mention log out link button, when i click log out link button it should be redirect to login page,,Pls Help

Answer (score 5):

From within the action method you can call `RedirectToAction` which has various overloads...

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
}
```

or simply call the `Redirect`...

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return Redirect("~/Home");
}
```